# What is the closest apporoximation for pdf of log-normal distribution?

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables, density-function

I am unable to compute a complex integral which uses the pdf of log-normal distribution. Hence, I want to replace the pdf of log-normal distribution with an alternate function(s) (piece-wise approximation is also fine) $f_X$$(x)$ which is a function of $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$ so that it best approximates the pdf of log-normal distribution.

How can I approximate the pdf of log-normal distribution? Which function can I use?

P.S: $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$ are the mean and variance of the gaussian random variable using which the log-normal variable is derived.

Comment: You can try Burr Distribution: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burr_distribution

Answer (score 1):

You can try to approximate the pdf on a closed interval $[\mu - \alpha \sigma,\mu + \alpha \sigma]$ by an [interpolation polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_interpolation).

Comment: Can you please elaborate your answer by considering an example?

Comment: @skt9 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial#Example_1

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to use numerical methods(interpolation etc), I would like to know if it is possible to replace the pdf by an alternative function under some conditions, like say a normal distribution when $\sigma$<<$\mu$(just an example, need not be true) or something like that?